# Creating a Facebook web app - would I be legally responsible for the data?

Tags: legal, privacy, facebook-application

I'm creating a discussion forum "web app" for a friend.

He want's me to add Facebook login to his site by creating a Facebook app.

Am I legally responsible for the data if I create the app under my Facebook account?

Who should register the Facebook app - the developer or the owner?

Can the right to the data be moved to a third-party after I finish configuring it?

I wish to prevent any possible future problems with privacy issues, I'm just doing a job, and I really don't want to have anything to do with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this SO question that answers your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940509/can-i-create-a-facebook-app-for-a-client-and-then-remove-myself#answer-8941756

Basically, you can transfer the app as long as your friend has a dev account